# Are there any ready to use app like events calendar in django

Tags: django, django-admin

I am building one django site but the client wants to have events calendar type thing where he can update the events and add picture to it.

Is there something i can use or i need to code everything by self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try: http://www.3captus.com/download/django_calendar